# writing function to index by variable name from two data frames in r to look up a value

Tags: r, function, lookup

I am trying to write a function to convert responses in two versions of a questionnaire, to be coded as “yes” or “no” based on response. Some of the questions were not answered so were coded as missing

```
#example data

q1 <- c("column 2", "column 2", "column 1", NA, "column 1")
q2 <- c("column 1", "column 2", "column 2", NA, "column 1")
q3 <- c("column 1", "column 2", "column 1", "column 2", "column 1")
version <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1)
xdat <- data.frame(cbind(q1, q2, q3, version))

 >   xdat
        q1       q2       q3 version
1 column 2 column 1 column 1       1
2 column 2 column 2 column 2       1
3 column 1 column 2 column 1       2
4     <NA>     <NA> column 2       2
5 column 1 column 1 column 1       1
```

I have created a dataframe of possible responses with character vectors for each of the yes or no responses by version, and a vector of the question number for each row.

```
#make dataframe of values for converting the two versions of the questionnaire)
v1y <- c("column 2", "column 2", "column 1")
v1n <- c("column 1", "column 1", "column 2")
v2y <- c("column 1", "column 2", "column 1")
v2n <- c("column 2", "column 1", "column 2")
q <- c("q1",  "q2",  "q3")
#create reference dataframe, with character values
yn.dat <- data.frame(cbind(q, v1y, v1n, v2y, v2n), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

> yn.dat
   q      v1y      v1n      v2y      v2n
1 q1 column 2 column 1 column 1 column 2
2 q2 column 2 column 1 column 2 column 1
3 q3 column 1 column 2 column 1 column 2
```

I then created a function to look up the version and index by the question variable in the data frame.

```
#function for calculating yes/no
yn.code <- function(v1y, v1n, v2y, v2n, q){
ifelse(xdat$version==1 & xdat[,q]==v1y, "yes", ifelse(xdat$version==2 & xdat[,q]==v2y, "yes", ifelse(xdat$version==1 & xdat[,q]==v1n, "no", ifelse(xdat$version==2 & xdat[,q]==v2n, "no", NA))))    
}
```

When I run the function it does not produce the correct values for yes and no for all responses.

```
#result
yn.res <- yn.code(yn.dat$v1y, yn.dat$v1n, yn.dat$v2y, yn.dat$v2n, yn.dat$q)

    > yn.res 
     q1    q2    q3   
[1,] "yes" "yes" NA   
[2,] NA    "yes" "no" 
[3,] "yes" NA    "yes"
[4,] NA    NA    NA   
[5,] NA    "no"  "yes"
```

It seems to code for NAs in the wrong places and it is not returning the right values.

At first I thought the function cycles through q in the yn.dat so it reads the fourth line of data and applies the rules of q1 to all responses of the fourth respondent, and rules of q2 to all responses of fifth respondent, but that doesn’t seem to match what’s going wrong.

Possibly I need to include an %in% argument in the function to look up the xdat variable name in yn.dat, then return the value I’m looking for?

Sorry if this is a simple programming thing, but I've been scratching my head with this for a while and am new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell you why exactly your code is not working. But such a convoluted use of `ifelse()` doesn't seem like a good idea.

A possible alternative is to create a look-up table. To that end, your data frame `yn.dat` needs to be converted to a different format. Depending on how you actually created `yn.dat`, it is maybe better to create it in that format from the start, but I can still show you, how to get there from your current format:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
# convert to long format
yn.dat2 <- gather(yn.dat, type, answer, -q)
# split type up into version and yes/no
yn.dat2 <- mutate(yn.dat2, version = as.numeric(substr(type, 2, 2)),
                  yn = ifelse(substr(type, 3, 3) == "y", "yes", "no")) %>%
          select(-type)
yn.dat2
##     q   answer version  yn
## 1  q1 column 2       1 yes
## 2  q2 column 2       1 yes
## 3  q3 column 1       1 yes
## 4  q1 column 1       1  no
## 5  q2 column 1       1  no
## 6  q3 column 2       1  no
## 7  q1 column 1       2 yes
## 8  q2 column 2       2 yes
## 9  q3 column 1       2 yes
## 10 q1 column 2       2  no
## 11 q2 column 1       2  no
## 12 q3 column 2       2  no
```

There is one row of data for each possible combination of question (`q`), column (`answer`) and `version` with the corresponding value of `"yes"` or `"no"`. Now, I'll define column names that uniquely characterise each row, which will enable me to look-up the table later:

```
row.names(yn.dat2) <- paste(yn.dat2$q, yn.dat2$answer, yn.dat2$version,
                            sep = "-")
```

Next, I define a function that uses the look-up table to convert a single column of `xdat`, characterised by its name, to `"yes"` or `"no"`:

```
do_one_q <- function(q) {
  keys <- paste(q, xdat[, q], xdat[, "version"], sep = "-")
  yn.dat2[keys, "yn"]
}
```

I creates the same kind of key that we used for the row names above from the values in xdat. Then that key is used to subset `yn.dat2`. Not that this also works to "convert" the `NA`s in `xdat` into `NA`s: The key for, e.g., the `NA` in `q1` is `"q1-NA-2"` and if you index with an non-existing key, `NA` is returned:

```
yn.dat2["q1-NA-2", "yn"]
## [1] NA
```

There is thus no need to treat missing values specially.

The last step is to apply this function to all the questions as follows:

```
qs <- paste0("q", 1:3)
xdat_new <- as.data.frame(lapply(qs, do_one_q))
names(xdat_new) <- qs
xdat_new
##     q1   q2  q3
## 1  yes   no yes
## 2  yes  yes  no
## 3  yes  yes yes
## 4 <NA> <NA>  no
## 5   no   no yes
```

#### Edit:

The conversion to long format can just as well be done with `melt()` instead of `gather()`. Just replace the line involving `gather()` by

```
library(reshape2)
# convert to long format
yn.dat2 <- melt(yn.dat, id = "q", variable.name = "type", value.name = "answer")
```

Comment: I will try this on my data, there are considerably more questions and possible combinations but this seems to be a better way to create a lookup table than I was using. I've only used 'reshape' to convert to data frames to long form before, so using 'gather' is new to me.

Comment: You can use `melt()` instead of `gather()` if you're more familiar with the former. I have added the code to the question.

Comment: While the solution works for my example, it doesn't for my actual data as it contains missing values for some questions and returns NAs. I tried including an 'na.rm=TRUE' argument to the do_one_q function, but this doesn't seem to help.

Comment: It's a bit hard to post a solution that takes care of problems that the date in your example does not have... Please do not post the updates to your question as a comment here, but rather edit the question itself. Also explain, what it means to have missing values in `yn.dat`. This table gives information about your questionnaire, not about the answers you got. I could understand missing values in `xdat`, which would correspond to unanswered question. But how can there be missing values in `yn.dat`? In your new example data, I would say that `q2` simply does not exist...

Comment: Apologies, have updated the data in the example above.

Comment: I have rerun the code using your new `xdat`  with the missing values and the code runs flawlessly as it is. I have edited my answer to include the new `xdat` and added a few remarks on why it works. But I still wonder what it was that did not work for you?

Comment: I have noticed that you haven't accepted an answer on any of your questions. If you received an answer that was useful, please consider accepting (and upvoting) it. This will help others that look for the best answer and you will even gain a little rep yourself.

Comment: I'm sorry I thought I'd already upvoted your much appreciated response. I too don't have the error using my example data but when I ran the code on my data it returned <NA>s but I realised I had not made the key id for the lookup table the row names, but just another vector in the table. It took me some time to work out what was going wrong in my own data but it works now, thank you!

Comment: I just realised the reason my up votes aren't publicly visible because I haven't reached a reputation of 15 yet. Not being unappreciative!

Comment: That's fine. But I was not just talking about the upvotes and this answer here. You can also mark an answer as accepted by clicking the check mark next to it. The idea is that you give this check mark to the answer that was most useful to you. Of course, if none of the answers you got did help, you are not forced to mark any of them. This will help the answerer by giving him reputation, future visitors by pointing out a useful answer, and you by giving you a little reputation yourself. Please also check your other question for good answers.